# Eliminating combinations of a list based on order of the another list

Tags: python

I have a list which consists of factors of a number in ascending order. I have generated the permutations of that list and now I need to eliminate the permutations having the same order as that of that original list of ascending factors.

Consider for eg:

```
Number=9
factors=1,3,9 
l=[1,3,9]
```

permutations of above list 1 are which I have stored as a list of list using permutations function In Python:

```
ll=[[1,3,9],[1,9,3],[3,1,9],[3,9,1],[9,1,3],[9,3,1]]
```

Now I need to eliminate the combinations having 2 or greater elements in the same order as that factors of 9 in ascending order:
removed from combinations:

```
[**[1,3,9]**,[**3,9**,1],[9,**1,3**]]
```

I just need :`[[1,9,3],[3,1,9],[9,3,1]`

Please help with the solutions, sets are unordered and hence not opted for.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share some portion of your code illustrating your problem? Use [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can filter the permutations while you generate them:

```
from itertools import permutations

def permutations_without_consecutive(lst):
    # Make permutations of elements with their index
    for perm in permutations(enumerate(lst)):
        # Check there are no contiguous indices in permutation
        if all(i2 - i1 != 1 for (i1, _), (i2, _) in zip(perm, perm[1:])):
            # Yield permutation tuple
            yield tuple(x for _, x in perm)

print(*permutations_without_consecutive([1, 3, 9]), sep='\n')
# (1, 9, 3)
# (3, 1, 9)
# (9, 3, 1)
```

Comment: What changes should be done if we have a lists of List for which we have to find the factors like if l=[[1,3,9],[1,2,5,10]]

Comment: @rajatshrivastav What would you want to get from that list exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply filter if the permutation has a pair from the original factor list.

```
original_pairs = {(l[i], l[i+1]) for i in range(len(l)-1)}

def has_original_pair(my_list, pairs):
    for i in range(len(my_list)-1):
        if (my_list[i], my_list[i+1]) in pairs:
            return True
    return False

filtered_ll = [x for x in ll if not has_original_pair(x, original_pairs)]
```

Comment: This logic isn't working when I have the number as 10,

Comment: Number=10                           
factors=1,2,5,10                                         
l=[1,2,5,10]                            ll=[[(1, 2, 5, 10), (1, 2, 10, 5), (1, 5, 2, 10), (1, 5, 10, 2), (1, 10, 2, 5), (1, 10, 5, 2), (2, 1, 5, 10), (2, 1, 10, 5), (2,5, 1, 10), (2, 5, 10, 1), (2, 10, 1, 5), (2, 10, 5, 1), (5, 1,2, 10), (5, 1, 10, 2), (5, 2, 1, 10), (5, 2, 10, 1), (5, 10, 1, 2), (5, 10, 2, 1), (10, 1, 2, 5), (10, 1, 5, 2), (10, 2, 1, 5), (10, 2, 5, 1), (10, 5, 1, 2), (10, 5, 2, 1)]]

Comment: @rajatshrivastav The `ll` here has an extra erroneous list around it (it's a list of list of tuples). Omit one of the parentheses, and it does work: 

`ll = [(1, 2, 5, 10), (1, 2, 10, 5), (1, 5, 2, 10), (1, 5, 10, 2), (1, 10, 2, 5), (1, 10, 5, 2), (2, 1, 5, 10), (2, 1, 10, 5), (2,5, 1, 10), (2, 5, 10, 1), (2, 10, 1, 5), (2, 10, 5, 1), (5, 1,2, 10), (5, 1, 10, 2), (5, 2, 1, 10), (5, 2, 10, 1), (5, 10, 1, 2), (5, 10, 2, 1), (10, 1, 2, 5), (10, 1, 5, 2), (10, 2, 1, 5), (10, 2, 5, 1), (10, 5, 1, 2), (10, 5, 2, 1)]`